# C# Hide all labels/ controls

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible within a windows form using C# to hide all specific controls upon form load, e.g. labels or buttons and then chose to show the ones that I wan't to be shown?

I've got a program which contains a lot of buttons and labels but I only want one or two shown upon load and I feel doing this method of `label1.Hide();` for every label seems inefficient but instead I could just show labels I want when I want. Maybe using a loop, something like this:

```
foreach (Label)
{
    this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: You can loop through the forms controls and check if they are what you want then hide them.

Comment: Put them in lists: List<Control> and use those to hide and show as needed. Note, that unless they sit in a FlowLayoutPanel, no other Control will change its location! Or set certain values to their Tags and test them when you want to show or hide some.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you could just hide them all in the designer, and then you wouldn't have to deal with hiding them at runtime.

If you do have to hide them at runtime, then you can grab all controls on the Form of a certain type with a little LINQ:

```
foreach (var lbl in Controls.OfType<Label>())
    lbl.Hide();
```

You could even filter the controls based on their name, so you only hide the ones you want to hide:

```
foreach (var lbl in Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(x => x.Name != "lblAlwaysShow"))
    lbl.Hide();
```

If they're also tucked inside of other controls, like Panels or GroupBoxes, you'll have to iterate through their ControlCollections too:

```
foreach (var lbl in panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>())
    lbl.Hide();

foreach (var lbl in groupBox1.Controls.OfType<Label>())
    lbl.Hide();
```

Comment: Hiding the controls in the designer didn't occur to me at the time, however the first one did the trick as well, i'm going to try both to see what suits my program the best, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 foreach(Label l in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
 {
    l.Visible=false;
 }

 this.myControl.Visible=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too with less code. It works another form controls (etc. Textbox, Button...)

```
foreach (Control lbl in Controls)
{
 if ((lbl) is Label)
 {
  lbl.Hide();
 }
}
```